# unable to derive VPC ID with Terraform AWS VPC module

Tags: amazon-web-services, module, terraform, amazon-vpc

I am trying to build an aws vpc and security groups in the same module.
I have this structure in my project:

```
.
├── README.md
├── commit.sh
├── main.tf
├── modules
│   └── networking
│       ├── README.md
│       ├── main.tf
│       ├── outputs.tf
│       └── variables.tf
├── plans
├── terraform.sh
├── variables.tf
├── vars
└── versions.tf
```

I am calling the module with a very simple main.tf in my project root:

```
## Networking
module "networking" {
  source = "./modules/networking/"
}
```

I am needing the VPC ID for the Security Groups, and the SGs are defined as different modules inside the same file as the VPC module:

```
module "web_ingress_sg" {
  source = "terraform-aws-modules/security-group/aws//modules/http-80"

  name        = "wordpress-ingress"
  description = "Security group for web-server with HTTP ports open within VPC"
  vpc_id      = module.vpc.vpc_id

  ingress_cidr_blocks = ["50.82.222.12/32"]
  computed_egress_with_source_security_group_id = [
    {
      rule                     = "http-80-tcpp"
      source_security_group_id = module.wordpress_instance_sg.security_group_id
    },
  ]
}
```

The VPC ID is defined in the outputs.tf file in the module, but I keep getting the error msg "The argument "vpc_id" is required, but no definition was found."

Comment: This is difficult to answer with your example being incomplete. Could you try to edit your question to provide a [mcve] please? Seeing how you've structured your modules would make it much easier to answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A module **can't reference its own outputs**. You have to get the vpc id directly. Assuming you have the vpc defined in this networking module, then the following should be enough:

```
vpc_id      = aws_vpc.vpc.vpc_id
```

Comment: Apologies, and thanks for responding, but my original post was incorrect. The SG modules are in the same file as the VPC module but they are independent modules. I am trying to pull the VPC ID from the VPC module with 'module.vpc.vpc_id'

Comment: @RobertCampbell Then you can't do that. You have to call your VPC module from root module, and past vpc_id obtained from the module as an input parameter to sg module. modules can't reference themselves.

Comment: Yes. It was clumsy naming conventions. I renamed the parent module "network" (called from root/main.tf) and then inside the network module I am defining  the new VPc. The new SGs are  in different modules from VPC, but all in parent module "network".  The SG modules call "module.network.vpc_id" and the plan is working now. Thanks for you help, you got me thinking more clearly about module composition.